# Android onMeasure( ) measuring width but not height

Tags: android, view, size, measure

I have a SurfaceView that i need to know the width and height of, the code looks like this:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    screenWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    screenHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

For some reason it manages to measure the width of this view but not the height of it, I've tried placing the height measurement before the width one to see if its just not calling the onMeasure() method quick enough but it didn't work.

Edit:

Heres all the code:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
Integer screenWidth, screenHeight;
static Integer score;
long lastTime = 0;
byte speed = 5;

static Boolean mute;
static String textureUsed = "space";

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mute = MainMenu.getMute();
    score = 0;
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// graphics are drawn here
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //covers the whole canvas in white to clear previouslly draw graphics
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    //set the location of the players selected texture pack
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(textureUsed, "drawable", "com.unreturnablestudios.FlipSide");
    //loads this texture pack
    Bitmap graphics = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);

    //src and dst are used to detarmine which parts of the image are
    //going to be used and where abouts on the screen they are going
    //to be displayed
    Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(graphics, src, dst, null);

    // sets the style of the text up
    String scoreString = Integer.toString(score);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);//red font
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);//Uses the players default font
    paint.setTextSize(screenWidth / 10);//font size
    //draws the text
    canvas.drawText(scoreString,0, 0, paint);
    score -= speed;
}

// deals with user touching the screen
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    double X = event.getX();

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (currentTime > lastTime + 100) {
        if (X < (screenWidth / 2) && X != 0) {

        } else {

        }
    }
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void launchEnd() {
    Context context = getContext();
    Intent openEnd = new Intent("com.unreturnablestudios.FlipSide.END");
    context.startActivity(openEnd);
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
}

public static Integer getScore() {
    // called by the End class and returns the score.
    return score;
}

public static boolean getMute() {
    // called by the End class and returns the boolean that is in control of
    // sound
    return mute;
}

// gets the measurements of the screen (width and height)
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    screenWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    screenHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

The weird thing is i have used onMeasure() before in a previous version of this application and it worked fine, but i decided to alter most of the code to try and make it run faster and now it won't work.

Comment: How do you instantiate it?  In code, or XML, please show as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

OnMeasure is often called multiple times by the layout process, have you checked that it's not called more than once?

Usually what I have seen is that for some layouts it's called the first time to measure the width of the view, and then once all of the view widths have been locked it's called a second time to measure the height.

Comment: I just had another look at the code and it seems that on measure wasn't the issue for some reason it was the src rectangle, i was trying to draw part of an image that was 480px heigh yet if i used the value 480 it cut off more then i needed making it look like the image wasn't correctly scaling.